# Can I get the function of the base class on object is created as interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I've got two classes: `Customer` and `TableViewCustomer`

```
public class Customer {

private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

public String getName()
{
    return name.get();
}
}
```

TableViewCustomer class:

```
public class CustomerTableView extends Customer implements TableViewFillModelInterfance{    

private ObservableList<CustomerTableView> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private Button actionButton;

(...)
}
```

Interface which implements extended class:

```
 public interface TableViewFillModelInterfance <T> {

    public Button getActionButton();

    Collection <T> getObservableList();

}
```

And now I need to create an object which is type of `TableViewFillModelInterfance`, but having a possiblity to get the Customer class's methods!
Something like this:

```
TableViewFillModelInterfance<T> item = new TableViewFillModelInterfance<T>();
item.getName(); 
 <------------------------------------------------->

TableViewCustomer item = new TableViewCustomer();
item.getItem(); //Its not what i want to!
```

`getName()` function is from base class Customer.class!
How can I achive that if i cannot create CustomerTableView object instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you received an object, and the only thing known about it is a certain interface, conformance to this interface *is the only thing guaranteed.*

If you know that there is a chance that the object *also* belogns to a certain class, you can check this, cast the object to that class, and call that class's methods.

Please make sure you handle the cases when the object you receive is *not* an instance of `CustomerTableView`.

Comment: You gave me an idea, I did this code checking in `if` instruction -> is this object instanceof appropriate class

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism can be used something like this.

```
TableViewFillModelInterfance<T> item = new CustomeTableView();
```

This way the object is of type super class in this case it is an interface, and the instance is CustomerTableView.

Comment: Yes, but what if I got a CarTableView() objects also? I want this code to work for all classes that implements TableViewFillModelInterfance, e.g: TableViewFillModelInterfance<T> item = new CarTableView();

Comment: yes then do as you mentioned e.g: TableViewFillModelInterfance<T> item = new CarTableView();, so for every class that has implemented your interface create a new object

Comment: Okey, but lets say I want to use this code in function, and I want to pass this as parameter either CarTableView or CustomerTableView. Your proposition won't work in that case, I dont know which element i will pass.

Comment: so use that function as a generic function, and pass the class object you want to use. So, you will pass a carTableView object if you want to use methods of that class.

There is no way possible you can specify something what you are trying to acheive. Because the super class(Interface) will be same for all sub class so you will need the object to be the type of interface